# How to pass returned data from a function to another function?

Tags: python, function, bluetooth, return

Been having trouble passing returned data from a function that can be used in another function. Here is the original code i wrote and it works fine but i would like add some of it into functions.
https://github.com/Octane70/Code/blob/master/Rouge/rouge2_main.py

Below is the portion of that code i would like to add functions too.
The data_received(data) function is pulling data from a bluetooth server that
I have running and i would like to pass the data to the two functions i created.
I get an error that the "data" is not defined on the                      command = data_received(data) line. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks?

```
def data_received(data):
    get_data1 = get_data2(data)
    return get_data1

command = data_received(data) 

def auto_manual(command):
    if command == "9":
        GPIO.output(26, True)
        GPIO.output(16, False)
        #manual_mode
        #auto_mode.exit() 
        print ("Green On")
   elif command == "11":
        GPIO.output(16, True)
        GPIO.output(26, False)
        #autoMode
        #manual_mode.terminate()
        print ("Blue On")

def manual_mode(command):
    #Dpad Forward
    if command == "1":
        rouge2_manual.Forward()
    elif command == "2":
        rouge2_manual.Stop()

        #Dpad Reverse
    elif command == "3":
         rouge2_manual.Reverse()
    elif command == "4":
         rouge2_manual.Stop()

    #Dpad Left
    elif command == "5":
         rouge2_manual.Left()
    elif command == "6":
         rouge2_manual.Stop()

    #Dpad Right
    elif command == "7":
         rouge2_manual.Right()
    elif command == "8":
         rouge2_manual.Stop()

BluetoothServer(data_received)
```

Comment: you want to pass in whatever your actually parameter is to `data_recieved()`, you are trying to pass in `data` which (apparently) has not yet been defined (initialized or assigned)

Comment: The error is because you haven't defined data. You are referencing "data" without telling Python what "data" is.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem thanks:

```
def data_received(data):
    auto_manual(data)
    manual_mode(data)

def auto_manual(command):
    if command == "9":
       GPIO.output(26, True)
       GPIO.output(16, False)
       #manual_mode
       #auto_mode.exit() 
       print ("Green On")
   elif command == "11":
        GPIO.output(16, True)
        GPIO.output(26, False)
        #autoMode
        #manual_mode.terminate()
        print ("Blue On")

def manual_mode(command):
    #Dpad Forward
    if command == "1":
       rouge2_manual.Forward()
    elif command == "2":
         rouge2_manual.Stop()

    #Dpad Reverse
    elif command == "3":
         rouge2_manual.Reverse()
    elif command == "4":
         rouge2_manual.Stop()

    #Dpad Left
    elif command == "5":
         rouge2_manual.Left()
    elif command == "6":
         rouge2_manual.Stop()

    #Dpad Right
    elif command == "7":
         rouge2_manual.Right()
    elif command == "8":
         rouge2_manual.Stop()

BluetoothServer(data_received)
pause()
```